# How can I play a video in XNA?

Tags: c#, video, xna

I want to play a video when I go in the "Credits" section, and after the video finishes it will stop playing and go to the main menu automatically (or navigate there when I press `Escape`).I also tried to play it in `update` method but it doesn't function because I get an error (it's not a code error).  My code:

```
int count==0;//the variable from main menu
Video vid;
VideoPlayer vidPlayer;
Texture2D texture;
Rectangle vidRect;

Initialize()
{
    vidPlayer=new VideoPlayer();
}


LoadContent()
{
    vid=Content.Load<Video>("credits");
    vidPlayer.Play(vid);// Can I play it in Update methd?
    vidRect= new Rectangle(0,0,800,600);
}

Update()
{
    //stuffs...

    if(count==5)
    {
        //if I press enter
        {
            count=6;
            //I want to play it here

            //if it finishes 
            {
                count=5;
            }

            //if I press Escape
            {
                count=5;
                //stop videoplayer
            }
        }
    }        

    //stuffs...
}

Draw()
{
    texture = vidPlayer.GetTexture();
    //stuffs..
    if(count==6)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture,vidRect,Color.White);
    }
}
```

It functions but it is played when I start the game, immediately. Can I manage it like I can manage the sound like SoundEffectInstance? Is there something for the videos too?

I solved this problem!!
I put in the update method the following code:

```
if(count !=5)
{
    vidPlayer.Stop();
}

if(count==5)
{
    vidPlayer.Play(vid);
}
```

First it wasn't function because i removed it from the loadContent and put it directly in update.

Comment: Move the `vidPlayer.Play(vid);` inside the Update method, and don't play it if it is already playing.

Comment: If I move it The game doesn't work